# Fnd the highest value of something and who that value belongs to in SQL

Tags: sql, max

In an SQL exercise my task is to find the highest value of something, and then find out who that value belongs to. The database consists of two different tables containing the number of things the person has bought, an order ID and a customer ID. The other table contains the order ID (as a primary key), forename, surname and the customerID (as a foreign key).

I'm trying to find the highest amount of items bought, use the customer ID to find out what their forename and surname are, and then display the forename, surname and items bought in a separate table.

Comment: Hi Bruce,
I don't think there is enough information. Where are you trying to get the items which are bought from?

Answer (score 0):

ok you got OrderID and CustomerID , to know the customerID with the most OrderID do this. you get the CustomerID with the highest amount of purchases (that is the most OrderID)

```
SELECT idCustomer,count(*) as cuenta
FROM test
group by idCustomer
having cuenta = (
    SELECT MAX(cuenta) FROM
    (
        SELECT idCustomer,count(*) as cuenta
        FROM test 
        group by idCustomer
    )
        as cuenta
)
```